# Navigate notification to screen it belongs in react-native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, push-notification, react-native

I have added push notification in my application which works fine.

I want to implement notifications such that, when a notification come on my device and I click on that notification, it should render me to that particular notification screen. currently I am using ios device.

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification

Comment: did you ever find a successful solution for this? I'm in the process of trying to figure it out as well now

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't add some more info for yourself in notification data payload which will be a pointer to yourself which screen do you want to render:

```
{
    foreground: false, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was received in foreground or not 
    userInteraction: false, // BOOLEAN: If the notification was opened by the user from the notification area or not 
    message: 'My Notification Message', // STRING: The notification message 
    data: {
         yourKey: 'value'
    }, // OBJECT: The push data 
}
```

Once you receive notification access that extra data field inside this function:

```
 onNotification: function(notification) {
         console.log( 'NOTIFICATION:', notification );
     },
```

Once you have done that, push corresponding screen on a view stack or dynamically generate view inside render function or set initialRoute to screen you wanna show. I assume you are using navigator for multiple screens.